# Rewrite match with single branch that doesn't depend on matched value

Tags: coq

I want to show the following:

```
match H in (_ = y) return y with
  | eq_refl => exist (fun n' : nat => n' < n) x0 l
  end = exist (fun n' : nat => n' < n) x0 l
```

I have in my context:

```
H : ltn n = ltn n
n : nat
x0 : nat
l : x0 < n
```

Where

```
Definition ltn (n : nat) : Type := {n' | n' < n}.
```

I'm unable to destruct on `H`, because the resulting term would be ill-typed, but it seems clear the equality holds because the only possible branch from match does not depend on what's being matched.

Comment: I think you probably need uniqueness of identity proofs (UIP) to achieve that unfortunately.

Comment: Or you can leverage the fact that the proposition at stake is decidable, thereby enjoys proof-irrelevance. See e.g. [this math-comp lemma](https://math-comp.github.io/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.eqtype.html#bool_irrelevance), [this stdlib lemma](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.Eqdep_dec.html#eq_proofs_unicity_on) or [that answer on TCS SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/5163/51245).

Comment: @ErikMD Is it really decidable? It is comparing two types, not two `nat`s. When I try it (see this [collacoq](https://x80.org/collacoq/deqoxelila.coq)) I end up with the goal `forall y : Type, ltn n = y \/ ltn n <> y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (as you said) is that Coq cannot destruct H, once it's a variable without "matchings" and the definition equality (that you are using) is based on normalization and string verification, you will not able to operate this. Anyway, without axioms, you can not destruct an equality instance, given that you are implying that all equalities are equals (definitional equals). The implication of considering all equalities as "equals" assumes that your core is [extensionally typed](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/axiom+UIP). For the sake of compatibility with others type theories (like homotopy type theory), Coq doesn't allow you to mention UIP without as axiom. UIP axiom and K axiom are very related. You can just export the axioms from [Coq standard library](https://coq.inria.fr/stdlib/Coq.Logic.EqdepFacts.html#EqdepElimination).

```
Theorem exact_eq : forall (n' n x0 : nat) (l : x0 < n) (H : {n' | n' < n} = {n' | n' < n}),
 match H in (_ = y) return y with
  | eq_refl => exist (fun n' : nat => n' < n) x0 l
  end = exist (fun n' : nat => n' < n) x0 l.

intros.
(*UIP_refl : forall (H : x = x), H = erefl x*) 
by set(@UIP_refl _ _ H); subst.
Qed.
```